# SSIS: Cannot Insert NULL

Tags: sql, ssis

Source have some column like  ID, Name, Phone and Address and destination has same column but one extra column Operator and want to put static text there during lookup transformation.Our destination has composite primary key ID+Operator.

I tried lookup transformation and working well.but want to add static text during lookup transformation.

...
...

Comment: `Source Data -> Lookup Transformation to obtain Operator value -> Destination` Is that the general flow?

Comment: What is this static text? Is it based on some existing field value or can be generated randomly

Answer (score 0):

check the destination table if  column Operator accept NULL value

Regards

Comment: John said that "Operator" is part of the Primary Key in the destination table. So it can't be nullable.